# Any ways to center/fill/position an element to a parent div with `position: static`?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome extension, which finds some specific `div`s from a web page, and adds a button inside each `div`.

Now I want to position my button in the exact center (vertically and horizontally) of the `div`, but these `div`s have the default `position: static` (which means I can't use absolute positioning if I understand it correctly).

For compatibility with other extensions, I don't want to modify the style of original elements (like setting the `position` of these `div`s). Is it possible then to position my buttons?

Comment: Your understanding is wrong and position:absolute will work just fine.

Comment: @Rob, I made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8L9y3yh6/1/), can you show me how it works?

Comment: You are required to post your markup here, not a third-party site which can change or disappear tomorrow helping no one else.

Comment: There are rules in place and, if you wish to participate in SO, you need to follow the rules. Those same rules, which you are not following, make your question of no value to anyone else when that code changes or disappears. Hence, my statement to you, earlier, to post your code here. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Can you add Flexbox to the div?

```
div {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

otherwise if you can only modify the button, use transform to center:

```
button {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;          
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
}
```

Comment: I can but I don't want to modify the styles of original elements. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: I edited my answer to center button using transforms

Comment: Umm, does not quite work for me. I made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8L9y3yh6/1/), can you show me how it works?

Comment: In your fiddle you can just add margin: 0 auto; to the #mybutton (after you get rid of comment). Not sure how to vertically align with all the preceding text? Pretty tough if you can't put position: relative on parent div :(